# Collections subtle differences in Java

Tags: java

Why we have to mention capacity in case of `PriorityQueue` constructor when
we are using comparator with `PriorityQueue`, which is not the case with
other collections where we use comparator and any sort of capacity in
the constructor is not mandatory and compiles fine while
in case of `PriorityQueue` if we have to use a comparator we have to
mention capacity else a compile time error is thrown.

```
class PQ  {
    PriorityQueue<Integer> pq2 = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(10, new PQ.PQSort());          

    static class PQSort implements Comparator<Integer> { 

        public int compare(Integer one, Integer two) {
            return two.compareTo(one);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the question?

Comment: Please separate your sentences correctly. I.e. add interpuctuation (. and ,). You have an interesting question which is worth thinking about, but your writing style is too difficult to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to ask the API designers.

I guess they just did not want to provide overloaded constructors for all possible combinations of optional arguments. So you just get the ones they think are most frequently used, and one with all options (where you have to provide defaults for the ones you don't care about).

Other languages solve this by having optional, named parameters with defaults. In Java, we are stuck with positional parameters (and the API designers choosing to provide as many convenient overrides as they see fit).

Answer (score -1):

even if you remove initial capacity also it works for me

priority queue has below constructors

1 `PriorityQueue()`

This creates a PriorityQueue with the default initial capacity (11) that orders its elements according to their natural ordering.

2 PriorityQueue(Colle`enter code here`ction c)

This creates a PriorityQueue containing the elements in the specified collection.

3 PriorityQueue(int initialCapacity)

This creates a PriorityQueue with the specified initial capacity that orders its elements according to their natural ordering.

4 `PriorityQueue(int initialCapacity, Comparator<? super E> comparator)`

This creates a PriorityQueue with the specified initial capacity that orders its elements according to the specified comparator.

5 `PriorityQueue(PriorityQueue<? extends E> c)` 
This creates a PriorityQueue containing the elements in the specified priority queue.

6 `PriorityQueue(SortedSet<? extends E> c)` 
This creates a PriorityQueue containing the elements in the specified sorted set.

this below code works

```
public class PqueueEx1 {
    PriorityQueue<Integer> pq2 = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(new PqueueEx1.PQSort());          

    static class PQSort implements Comparator<Integer> { 

        public int compare(Integer one, Integer two) {
            return two.compareTo(one);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: no its not working shows same error where u have to insert the capacity.